# How to chain Ternary Operators?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I show different Data based on values in Ternary Operator in Multiple conditions:

I have this one,

```
 [attr.data-pendo]="linkedItemType === LinkedItemType.Prospect ? 'pendo-prospects' : 'pendo-loans'"
```

I need to add 1 more condition,

so it is like:

```
 if linkedItemType === LinkedItemType.Prospect then 'pendo-prospects' 
 if linkedItemType === LinkedItemType.Loan then 'pendo-loan' 
 else 'pendo-task'
```

How make this in Ternary?

Comment: Nothing you posted looks like legitimate C#. It looks a little like JavaScript (the operators), or maybe a little like Python (lack of delimiters around `if` statement expressions). If this is in fact a [tag:c#] question, please explain in what way. If it's not C#, then please fix the tag. In either case, please explain why you can't just add the other condition in the ternary expression by using the usual Boolean operators and composition.

Comment: It should be noted that pushing everything in to conditional operators *one-liners* can reduce readability

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the way:

```
linkedItemType == LinkedItemType.Prospect ? "pendo-prospects" : linkedItemType == LinkedItemType.Loan ? "pendo-loan" : "pendo-task";
```

Or, the same thing broken onto different lines for readability:

```
linkedItemType == LinkedItemType.Prospect ? "pendo-prospects" 
: linkedItemType == LinkedItemType.Loan ? "pendo-loan" 
: "pendo-task";
```