# Does C# have any equivalent to Elixir's `cond`?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements, elixir

In Elixir, if I want to check multiple boolean conditions, rather than some ugly mess of if/else logic, I can elegantly do this:

```
guess = 46
number_of_guesses = 3
cond do
   number_of_guesses > 5 -> 
      IO.puts "Too many guesses!  You lose."

   guess == 46 -> 
      IO.puts "You guessed 46!"

   guess == 42 -> 
      IO.puts "You guessed 42!"

   true        -> 
      IO.puts "I give up."
end
```

The above program generates the following result −

> You guessed 46!

(Example derived from [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/elixir/elixir_decision_cond.htm), but further contrived to demonstrate not every expression must contain the same variable.)

Does C# have anything similar or would I need to use if/else?

Comment: You could use switch case

Comment: You could do it in one line `result = "But this will"` the rest is a waste of time

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik, unless I'm missing something, that's not how a switch works... unless you mean to use guard statements....

Comment: @TheGeneral, I think you missed the point.  This is just example code.  In a real solution, there should be variables to evaluate in each condition.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Comment: @TheGeneral, you are still missing the point as I'm looking to evaluate an arbitrary collection of expressions which each evaluate to a boolean, not match a value.

Comment: What's the point of `cond` variable in this statement? It seems to be not used at all.

Comment: @Evk, `cond` is not a variable, it is a keyword.  See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/elixir/elixir_decision_cond.htm

Comment: Now after your edit, you are simply "matching a value", so which is it? "Evaluate an arbitrary collection of expressions which each evaluate to a boolean" or "match a value"?

Comment: `if-else-if` is not ugly. It's beautiful!

Comment: I don't think there is direct analog of this in C# (can't say I miss it though).

Comment: @Sweeper, while this example is always comparing `guess`, that does not need to be the case.  I'll come up with a more contrived example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are matching against a value in almost all of the cases, you can still use a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), with case guards:

```
int guess = 46;
int numberOfGuesses = 3;
Console.WriteLine(
    guess switch {
        _ when numberOfGuesses > 5 => "Too many guesses!  You lose.",
        46 => "You guessed 46!",
        42 => "You guessed 42!",
        _ => "I give up."
    }
);
```

Notice that in the first arm, I matched anything (the underscore `_` pattern) but only "when numberOfGuesses > 5". Or in this case you can even do fancier pattern matching:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    (guess, numberOfGuesses) switch
    {
        (_, > 5) => "Too many guesses!  You lose.",
        (46, _) => "You guessed 46!",
        (42, _) => "You guessed 42!",
        _ => "I give up."
    }
);
```

But of course, this is not possible in every situation.

If all the arms are unrelated conditions, using this sort of `_ when ...` construct feels a bit abusive, so alternatively, you can use a [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885773/how-to-chain-ternary-operators) of [ternary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
var x = 
    condition1 ?
        someValue1 :
    condition2 ?
        someValue2 :
    condition3 ?
        someValue3 :
    valueWhenNoConditionsAreTrue;
```

Though I feel even this can be a bit [astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) on first sight.

If you want to execute *statements* in those branches, rather than expressions, then you should just use a plain-old if-else-if structure, or if pattern matching can be used, a switch statement (but note that the `_ when ...` trick can't be used in a switch statement).